# Get ratio of column values for different rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

| Date | Route | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | A | 99 | 26 |
| 01/02/2020 | A | 37 | 96 |
| 01/03/2020 | A | 20 | 83 |
| 01/01/2021 | A | 50 | 79 |
| 01/02/2021 | A | 16 | 50 |
| 01/03/2021 | A | 52 | 33 |
| 01/01/2020 | B | 48 | 44 |
| 01/02/2020 | B | 96 | 30 |
| 01/03/2020 | B | 17 | 42 |
| 01/01/2021 | B | 34 | 74 |
| 01/02/2021 | B | 49 | 37 |
| 01/03/2021 | B | 70 | 12 |

I need to get the ratio for Col1 and Col2 based on 2020 and 2021 values. That is, a new column for each month that has Col2/Col1.

I have tried a few approaches (pct_change, diff), but I am unable to get the right result. I also made a DateTimeIndex to help me with this, but wasn't able to get the ratio.

This is the gist of what I am trying to do, but not sure how to frame the .loc command in this scenario:

```
df['Col1_ratio'] = df['Col2'] / df.loc(<get index of previous year's row>)['Col1']
```

This is the expected output dataframe:

| Date | Route | Col1 | Col2 | Col1_ratio | Col2_ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | A | 99 | 26 | NA | NA |
| 01/02/2020 | A | 37 | 96 | NA | NA |
| 01/03/2020 | A | 20 | 83 | NA | NA |
| 01/01/2021 | A | 50 | 79 | 0.505050505 | 3.038461538 |
| 01/02/2021 | A | 16 | 50 | 0.432432432 | 0.520833333 |
| 01/03/2021 | A | 52 | 33 | 2.6 | 0.397590361 |
| 01/01/2020 | B | 48 | 44 | NA | NA |
| 01/02/2020 | B | 96 | 30 | NA | NA |
| 01/03/2020 | B | 17 | 42 | NA | NA |
| 01/01/2021 | B | 34 | 74 | 0.708333333 | 1.681818182 |
| 01/02/2021 | B | 49 | 37 | 0.510416667 | 1.233333333 |
| 01/03/2021 | B | 70 | 12 | 4.117647059 | 0.285714286 |

E.g. Col1_ratio is Col1_JAN21 / Col1_JAN20, and so on.

Comment: Kindly add the expected output dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create `MultiIndex` and then add one year for datetimes in `rename`, divide columns and add suffix by [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html), last add to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Date','Route'])

df2 = df1.rename(lambda x: x + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1), level=0)

df3 = df1[['Col1','Col2']].div(df2[['Col1','Col2']]).add_suffix('_ratio')

df = df.join(df3, on=['Date','Route'])
print (df)
         Date Route  Col1  Col2  Col1_ratio  Col2_ratio
0  2020-01-01     A    99    26         NaN         NaN
1  2020-01-02     A    37    96         NaN         NaN
2  2020-01-03     A    20    83         NaN         NaN
3  2021-01-01     A    50    79    0.505051    3.038462
4  2021-01-02     A    16    50    0.432432    0.520833
5  2021-01-03     A    52    33    2.600000    0.397590
6  2020-01-01     B    48    44         NaN         NaN
7  2020-01-02     B    96    30         NaN         NaN
8  2020-01-03     B    17    42         NaN         NaN
9  2021-01-01     B    34    74    0.708333    1.681818
10 2021-01-02     B    49    37    0.510417    1.233333
11 2021-01-03     B    70    12    4.117647    0.285714
```